# Get 0 if record doesn't exists of same day

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do is getting data for analytics which is working fine except one thing only, I am getting total records of date, previous total records of same days and total record of particular day, which is working absolutely fine.

But the only issue is I want data of those days also which have no rows

For example :
I have data for 1 sept, 2 sept, 3 sept and 6 sept but I want result for 4 & 5 sept also with 0 total.

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(ActivityID) FROM Activity WHERE DATE(CreatedDate) BETWEEN '2015-08-31' AND '2015-09-07'
) as total_post, (SELECT COUNT(ActivityID) FROM Activity WHERE DATE(CreatedDate) BETWEEN '2015-08-23'
 AND '2015-08-30') as previous_total_post, DATE_FORMAT(DATE(CreatedDate), '%d %b, %y') as date, COUNT
(ActivityID) as total
FROM (`Activity`)
WHERE DATE(CreatedDate) BETWEEN '2015-08-31' AND '2015-09-07'
GROUP BY `date`
ORDER BY `CreatedDate` ASC
```

Comment: You have to build a calendar table somehow and then `LEFT JOIN` your table to this one.

Comment: is there any way to do it without creating any table but we can use virtual table or something like that ?

Comment: If it's only for Sptember you can create an inline view using `UNION`.

Comment: no date will come dynamic it could be any date

Comment: Consider posting up an sqlfiddle AND a desired result

Comment: You mention PHP , so you can handle the logic of missing dates there , in a simple loop

Comment: It is already implemented by php but I want it from query if possible

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d48e4/2

Comment: its returning 1st sept, 2nd sept and 4th sept but 3rd sept should also return with 0 and till end date whether record exists or not it should return if not exits then 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it-

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.date_field, '%d %b, %y') AS 'DATE', 
COUNT(IF(b.CreatedDate>='2015-08-31 00:00:00' AND b.CreatedDate<='2015-09-07 23:59:59',b.ActivityID,NULL)) AS total_post, 
COUNT(IF(b.CreatedDate>='2015-08-23 00:00:00' AND b.CreatedDate<='2015-08-30 23:59:59',b.ActivityID,NULL)) AS previous_total_post, 
COUNT(b.ActivityID) total 
from 
(
  SELECT date_format(date_field, '%Y-%m-%d') as date_field FROM
(
    SELECT
        MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()),1) +
        INTERVAL (MONTH(NOW())-2) MONTH +
        INTERVAL daynum DAY date_field
    FROM
    (
        SELECT t*10+u daynum
        FROM
            (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) A,
            (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
            UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
            UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
        ORDER BY daynum
    ) AA
) AAA
WHERE date_field >= '2015-08-23' and date_field < '2015-09-08') a 
LEFT JOIN `Activity` AS b ON a.date_field=DATE(b.CreatedDate) 
GROUP BY a.date_field
ORDER BY a.date_field ASC
```

Please updated query for multiple years-

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(a.date_field, '%d %b, %y') AS 'DATE', 
    COUNT(IF(b.CreatedDate>='2015-08-31 00:00:00' AND b.CreatedDate<='2015-09-07 23:59:59',b.ActivityID,NULL)) AS total_post, 
    COUNT(IF(b.CreatedDate>='2015-08-23 00:00:00' AND b.CreatedDate<='2015-08-30 23:59:59',b.ActivityID,NULL)) AS previous_total_post, 
    COUNT(b.ActivityID) total 
    from 
    (
      SELECT date_format(date_field, '%Y-%m-%d') as date_field FROM
    (
SELECT
    MAKEDATE(YEAR(SUBDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 YEAR)),1) +
    INTERVAL (MONTH(NOW())-9) MONTH +
    INTERVAL daynum DAY date_field
FROM (
    SELECT m*1000+h*100+t*10+u daynum
    FROM
 (SELECT 0 m UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) D,
    (SELECT 0 h UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) C,
        (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) A,
        (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
        UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
        UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
    ORDER BY daynum

        ) AA
    ) AAA
    WHERE date_field >= '2010-01-01' and date_field < '2015-09-08') a 
    LEFT JOIN `Activity` AS b ON a.date_field=DATE(b.CreatedDate) 
    GROUP BY a.date_field
    ORDER BY a.date_field ASC
```

Comment: its returning 1st sept, 2nd sept and 4th sept but 3rd sept should also return with 0 and till end date whether record exists or not it should return if not exits then 0

Comment: please check updated query now, you can also check sqlfiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d48e4/31.

Comment: Hi sorry for 1 more question but what if I select date of 1 january 2000 till now then it returns records from 1 august 2015 only

Comment: you can change "MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()),1)" to "MAKEDATE(YEAR(SUBDATE(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 YEAR)),1)" and same need to change date range in query....

Comment: I did that one but it will return maximum 40 records